# How much time is it necessary for an electron app certificate to build enough trust?

Tags: windows, certificate, electron, code-signing

I have signed my electron application on Windows with an Code Signing Certificate. According to https://www.electron.build/code-signing, the app will show "a warning during installation that goes away once enough users installed your application and you've built up trust".

My question is, what is the number range of users that have to install my application in order for my certificate to be trusted?

This is crucial for us since we are launching a beta this week and would like to avoid showing the message.

Comment: this can be useful: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/139520

Comment: Thank you, we indeed ended up getting the EV certificate.